# Bring child form to front of MDI from that has Panel control

Tags: vb.net

I need to apply DoubleClick event on a MDI form, to do that i placed a Panel1 control on MDI form and make its dock as fill.
But when i call any child form, it's run in back of Panel1.
I tried this code in many events of MDI form and Child Form:

```
childForm.TopMost = true  
childForm.BringToFront = true
```

but it doesn't working!

Comment: Why would you dock fill a panel in an MDI form?  You took away all the space for the child forms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the PowerPacks DLL and use a Shape instead. Here is an example

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks

Public Class MDIParent1
    Dim C As New ShapeContainer
    Dim WithEvents R As New RectangleShape

    Private Sub MDIParent1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        C.Parent = Me
        R.Parent = C
        R.Top = 0
        R.Left = 0
        Me.Controls.Add(C)

    End Sub

    Private Sub MDIParent1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize

        R.Height = Me.Height
        R.Width = Me.Width

    End Sub

    Private Sub R_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles R.DoubleClick

        MessageBox.Show("Shape Double-click")

    End Sub
...
End Class
```

Anywhere you double-click that is not on a child form you should see that message.